# Python histogram error bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add error bars to a histogram with the following method:

`data=np.random.normal(10,1,100)
plt.hist(data,bins=np.arange(0,20,0.5),normed=1)
plt.errorbar(argument, argument,yerr=0.01)`

What arguments should I use in order to plot error bars on the top of each bin? I prefer sticking to this method of plotting...Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the result of [`plt.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

```
data = np.random.normal(10,1,100)
n, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(0,20,0.5),normed=1)
mid = 0.5*(bins[1:] + bins[:-1])
plt.errorbar(mid, n, yerr=0.01, fmt='none')
```

The line `mid = 0.5*(bins[1:] + bins[:-1])` just calculates the midpoint of the bars.